# R Multithreaded database access

Tags: multithreading, r, rmysql

I have a  a bunch of computation that needs to be done in parallel. In this computation the database is accessed through one global channel. So it is something like this:

```
library(doMC)
registerDoMC(2)
channel <<- connect_to_database()
results <- foreach(i=indexes) %dopar% {
    data <- get_data_from_db(channel)
    result <- do_computations(data)
}
```

But them I get this error:

```
task 1 failed - "cannot open the connection"
```

The reason, very probably is because the threads are accessing the channel simultaneously. Is there a way to put a mutex around the get_data_from_db? Or create more connections and check if there is a free one before accessing it? Any suggestions?

Thanks a lot!

---------------Edit--------------
Now I am creating one connection for each index. But I'm getting this error now:

```
task 1 failed - "expired MySQLConnection"

library(doMC)
registerDoMC(2)
channel<<-list()
for(i=indexes){
   channel[[i]] <-connect_to_database(...)
}

results <- foreach(i=indexes) %dopar% {
    data <- get_data_from_db(channel[[ind]])
    result <- do_computations(data)
}
```

Comment: Why can't you simply let each worker create a connection to the DB?

Comment: Yeah, I'm pretty sure the `channel` needs to be opened by each of the workers. The code above should work serially with `%do%`, but not in parallel.

Comment: Or get all the data in one query then send pieces to multiple workers?

Comment: I would like to reuse existing connections to gain time.

Comment: Reusing connections isn't going to save much (any?) time.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Each time I connect to the db, it takes around 3-4 seconds. Now I am creating global channels, but the second time I try to execute the loop, it says the connection has expired. But if I use each channel individually, it works.